# How to Access Database from server through a VPN

Tags: iphone, ios, database, web-services, vpn

I am working on an iphone app in which i want to access database from server through a VPN

Edit as i search. connection To server through is VPN is difficult and i was not found any solid information about this SO now i divide my Question in to two parts and part 1 is important to do as compare to other

Question 1
i have a SQL server DATABASE and a live ip of this server and i want to establish connection  and access database through iphone . mean i iphone app store, select data or perform any DDL or DML methods from it self?
e.g
 when user givs its info iPhone apps saves it on SQL SERVER DATABASE

Question 2
how can i do this all or which mean of communication is best through VPN how can i do and how can i hit or live IP?

Comment: ummmmmmm.  Where to begin...  You tagged this question with Web Services, so I'm going to go with that.  You will want to create a web service that responds to a restful api for doing you database transactions.  I don't think you could possibly create a vpn connection from within your app.

Comment: acctually i have no idea how to do this and web-service is also same like option this thats why i tag

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8799129/accessing-web-services-over-vpn-in-ios-iphone-ipad
here is an Question almost which i need but not 100% same to my situation :(

Answer (score 1):

You need a setup with a VPN-Gateway, which your iPhone is connecting to and some infrastructure behind the VPN-Gateway: at minimum the server the database is running on. The VPN connection can be setup in the iPhone Settings (you need the IP of your VPN-Gateway, Account, Password...), this has to be done manually and can't be controlled by the App. Once the VPN is setup and activated you can access the database as you would do it with any other App.

Edit: Question 2: I'm not sure if VPN is the right choice here. Is your server publicly available or is it inside an intranet? If it's publicly available a SSL/TLS connection would be the better choice instead of a VPN.